# Are you able to call 3 for loops in a specific order?

Tags: java

At the moment I have 3 loops, is it possible to call them one time instead of 3? The problem lies in the fact that loop one has to be finished before loop 2 can work, and loop 2 has to be finished before loop 3 can be run. So at the moment it's something like this.

```
public void handling() {
    for (Object object : Code.objects) {
        handle_One(object);
    }
    for (Object object : Code.objects) {
        handle_Two(object);
    }
    for (Object object : Code.objects) {
        handle_Three(object);
    }
}
```

If I try something like this it doesn't work because they are all being called at the same time and it has to be ordered.

```
public void handling() { //Code that doesn't work...
    for (Object object : Code.objects) {
        handle_One(object);
        handle_Two(object);
        handle_Three(object);
    }
}
```

Is there any way around this, any way to fix it? Have been trying for a while now and nothing...Having 3 for loops is very bad in this situation and causing problems. (And sadly the only way we can get it working)

Edit: The reason this is bad in my case is because the for loop can reach up to 300 sometimes. (As Code.objects, represents how many connections there are, sometimes its 100, meaning it's doing 300 loops per iteration.

Comment: What problems is it causing?  If you need to perform handle_one on the entire array before doing any handle_two's, then three loops is the only way.

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly what is wrong with having three `for` loops, considering that that seems to achieve the purpose you describe.

Comment: What is bad about having three non-nested loops?

Comment: This may go better if you tell us exactly what it is that you need to be doing...  You are describing the problem in such a way that it has no solution, i.e. "I want to do X, but I can't do X, what do I do?"  In addition, I don't think the 'problem' you see here is really a problem;  300 iterations will cost about the same whether it's in 1 for loop or 3, it's the meat of the loop that matters.

Comment: I'm not sure how sticking everything into a single loop would fix anything for you anyway: there's not really much difference between 3 things 100 times and 1 thing 100 times 3 times. If your performance is unacceptable when the number of objects is large, then you'll need to improve the algorithm itself rather than trying to randomly rearrange loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwigUtilities.invokeAndWait(<your task>`). Please refer the following link

[SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html)